# How can I set the default view for an 2sxc app?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Is there a way to make a certain template for an app the “default” template? Let’s say I have an app called “Photo Gallery” and it has 3 templates:

1. Carousel
2. Grid
3. Photo Album

By default, when dropped on the page, “Carousel” will show because it’s alphabetically the first option. I know that if I were to “hide” the view “Carousel” from the user, the “Grid” would be the default option. But what if I want all 3 options, I just want “Grid” to be the default template that’s chosen?

Is there a way to set a "default view" for a 2sxc app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, but it's hidden ;)

Go to the view Metadata and add an IsDefault decorator ;)

[image]

The effect will be a bit different depending on Content vs. App use. In Content, you can set a default for each content-type.

Without this, it will be A-Z priority.

Comment: My mind is blown. Great Q and answer!!